# DPI-aware manifest NOT embedding

Tags: c#, manifest, dpi, dpi-aware

I have tried everything imaginable. I have a winform that simply refuses to embed the DPIaware setting in my manifest within the exe. When I copy the exe to another machine to run, I MUST copy the manifest or it will not scale properly. If I add the manifest on the target (copied-to) machine, it is all good. If I delete the manifest (from the target machine), my app fails to autoscale.

**I have already chosen the manifest in the properties tab. I have already set the manifest to "Embedded resource". I have tried literally everything I have researched. Nothing works.**

How oh how can I compile the manifest (with my DPIaware settings) into the exe so I DO NOT have to copy the exe.manifest every single time?

[image: Manifest selection]

Comment: What type of project is it? I tried with a WinForms exe and the manifest worked for me without having to deploy it.

Comment: Just a regular C# Windows Form. Driving me bonkers!

Comment: I had a similar issue and for me the app.manifest was damaged - I had compatibility entries at the wrong place)

Comment: have you verified that the manifest is valid?

Comment: @DPIsht did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.